# Setting function to property in Backbone.js is giving me an error, but it works if I set it in the initialize method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

```
    ,debouncedAjax: _.debounce(_.bind(myFunction, this), 2000)

,request: function(requestParams, response){
    this.debouncedAjax(requestParams, response);
}
```

when I can request, I get this

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
>   (anonymous function)

If i set the result of that debounce function on the debouncedAjax property like this

```
    ,initialize: function() {               
      this.debouncedAjax = _.debounce(this.imoveisAjaxRequest, 2000);           
    }
```

It works fine !

WHY ?

BTW: debounce is a function from the AMAZING underscore.js framework !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As so many things in Javascript, it comes down to what the `this` pointer means.

In the first instance, you're probably defining a class prototype. If not explicity, then inside a Backbone.something.extend() call, which is the same thing. At that point, you're binding a function with `_.bind(myFunction, this)`. So what does the `this` pointer refer to at that point? It's certainly not any particular instance of the object, because they haven't been created yet. It's probably either `window` or something in the Backbone framework.

When you call that function in the `initialize` function, the `this` pointer means what you want it to, so everything works out as you want it to.

Comment: So there is no other way to do it ?

Comment: Not if you want to retain the meaning of `this`. Also, I think if you debounce the function in the prototype, it will debounce across all instances of the class. I'm not sure if debounce will give you correct results in that case - it may drop some calls that you'd rather it didn't.

Comment: @Cfontes: Generally, anything that needs `_.bind` or `_.bindAll` is done inside `initialize` so that `this` is what you want it to be. Hence the `_.bindAll(this, ...)` stuff you see in many view constructors.